# How would I loop through a json file?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a verification system where people link their accounts on two different platforms. I've got the code working, but now I need to check if the code is valid. I'm using .forEach on the json file, yet I keep getting the error:

client.verificationCodes.forEach is not a function

and it crashes.

Here is what the json file looks like:

[my json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmyNw.png)

Here is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const rbx = require('noblox.js')
const fs = require("fs")
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

const client = new Discord.Client()
client.verificationCodes = require("./codes.json")

require("dotenv").config()
const port = process.env.PORT
const serverKey = process.env.SERVER_KEY
const cookie = process.env.COOKIE

function randomString(length, chars) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
    return result;
}

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Client is ready.")
})

app.post("/getVerificationCode", function(req,res,next) {
    console.log("Recieved")
    if (req.body.serverKey !== serverKey) {
        console.log("Invalid serverKey supplied.")
        
        return res.status(403).json({
            error: "You do not have permission to use this."
        })
    }

    let verificationCode = randomString(4,'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ').toUpperCase()
    const userID = parseInt(req.body.userid)
    console.log(verificationCode)

    client.verificationCodes[userID] = {
        code: verificationCode
    }

    fs.writeFile("./codes.json", JSON.stringify(client.verificationCodes,null,4), err => {
        if (err) throw err
    })

    return res.status(200).json({
        VerificationCode: verificationCode
    })
})

app.get("/*", function(req,res,next) {
    return res.status(200).json({})
})

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("!verify")) {
      let args = message.content.split(" ")
      if (!args[1]) {
        message.reply("You must specify a code.")
        return
      }
      client.verificationCodes.forEach(vCode => {
          if (vCode.Code === args[1]) {
              let username = rbx.getUsernameFromId(vCode)
              message.member.setNickname(username)
          }
      })
    }
  })

app.listen(port)
console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`)

function rbxLogin(newCookie) {

    try {
        rbx.setCookie(newCookie)
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(`Invalid cookie supplied, or expired. ${err}`)
    }


}

// rbxLogin(cookie)



client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)
```

I appreciate help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! JSON !== JS object. You probably need to `JSON.parse()` first. Even after you do, `forEach` is an array function, not an object function, so use `Object.keys`, `Object.values` or `Object.items` first or index into the property you want.

Comment: Along with `JSON.parse()`, you can't iterate through a JS object with `forEach`. Instead, use `for (const [property, value] in client.verificationCodes) {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a syntax error because .forEach doesn't work on objects but on array and since that client.verificationCodes is an object then you need to use `Object.entries` to convert that to array of key, value.

I've refactored the block causing this error please use this:

```
Object.entries(client.verificationCodes).forEach(([key, vCode]) => {
          if (vCode.Code === args[1]) {
              let username = rbx.getUsernameFromId(vCode)
              message.member.setNickname(username)
          }
      })
```

which will make your whole code like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const rbx = require('noblox.js')
const fs = require("fs")
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

const client = new Discord.Client()
client.verificationCodes = require("./codes.json")

require("dotenv").config()
const port = process.env.PORT
const serverKey = process.env.SERVER_KEY
const cookie = process.env.COOKIE

function randomString(length, chars) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
    return result;
}

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Client is ready.")
})

app.post("/getVerificationCode", function(req,res,next) {
    console.log("Recieved")
    if (req.body.serverKey !== serverKey) {
        console.log("Invalid serverKey supplied.")
        
        return res.status(403).json({
            error: "You do not have permission to use this."
        })
    }

    let verificationCode = randomString(4,'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ').toUpperCase()
    const userID = parseInt(req.body.userid)
    console.log(verificationCode)

    client.verificationCodes[userID] = {
        code: verificationCode
    }

    fs.writeFile("./codes.json", JSON.stringify(client.verificationCodes,null,4), err => {
        if (err) throw err
    })

    return res.status(200).json({
        VerificationCode: verificationCode
    })
})

app.get("/*", function(req,res,next) {
    return res.status(200).json({})
})

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("!verify")) {
      let args = message.content.split(" ")
      if (!args[1]) {
        message.reply("You must specify a code.")
        return
      }
      Object.entries(client.verificationCodes).forEach(([key, vCode]) => {
          if (vCode.Code === args[1]) {
              let username = rbx.getUsernameFromId(vCode)
              message.member.setNickname(username)
          }
      })
    }
  })

app.listen(port)
console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`)

function rbxLogin(newCookie) {

    try {
        rbx.setCookie(newCookie)
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(`Invalid cookie supplied, or expired. ${err}`)
    }


}

// rbxLogin(cookie)



client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)
```

Comment: Okay that got rid of the error, yet now when I run console.log(vCode.Code) in the loop, undefined gets printed.

My json file looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmyNw.png

Comment: for that because you have a typo with `Code` you should use lower case `code` 
 same as in your json file,, because JS is a case sensitive language

Comment: Hm, now I have a very weird problem. It now logs the right code, yet in the if statment, they do not equal each other, as in the strings look the same but aren't for some reason, otherwise the console.log I added in after if (vCode.Code === args[1]) would log something, yet it doesn't.